# Configure Atom to work with Python, some packages are missing

Tags: python, atom-editor

I want to Configure `Atom` to work with `python` so after downloading the newest `version` from official website I notice that I cannot find many `packages` like `file icons`, `minimap` and the most important for me it `autocomplete-python` (again, missing...)

[image]

It just did not return any results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to load the 'Script' package which will allow you to run python scripts from the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are browsing your currently installed packages, if you go to settings you will see the "Install" button like this:

[image]

I hope this helps :)